# What are the values of 8 coordinates of viewing frustum which has angle 'theta' at the origin?

Tags: opengl, frustum

Near clipping plane is at 'n' units distance. Far clipping plane is at 'f' units from origin. z-axis is pointing right screen, y-axis pointing up and x-axis pointing outside the screen. Assuming aspect ratio of 1.

Comment: z and y are pointing in the same direction?

Comment: Y axis pointing up. It's a typo. Corrected

Comment: What is your aspect ratio (what is the width/height of your screen)?

Comment: Assume aspect ratio as 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing some basic trig you can get the width and height of the near and far plane, of the near plane they will be `2* tan(theta/2) * n` and the far plane will be `2* tan(theta/2) * f`

So the 8 values will be

```
(-n, n*tan(theta/2), n*tan(theta/2)), 
(-n, -n*tan(theta/2), n*tan(theta/2)), 
(-n, n*tan(theta/2), -n*tan(theta/2)), 
(-n, -n*tan(theta/2), -n*tan(theta/2)), 
(-f, f*tan(theta/2), f*tan(theta/2)), 
(-f, -f*tan(theta/2), f*tan(theta/2)), 
(-f, f*tan(theta/2), -f*tan(theta/2)), 
(-f, -f*tan(theta/2), -f*tan(theta/2))
```